# Array triplet show only once

Tags: arrays, function, triplet

I have this function:
int triplet(int *array, int size, int K) {
    int i, j, k;

```
for(i = 0; i < size-2; i++) {
   for (j = i+1; j < size-1; j++) {
       for (k = j+1; k < size; k++) {
       /* Check if the sum of current triplets
       is equal to "K" */
           if(array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == K) {
             printf("Triplet Found : %d, %d, %d\n", array[i], array[j], array[k]);
             return 1;
           }           
       }
   }
}
/* No triplet found whose sum is equal to K */
return 0;}
```

But it only shows 1 triplet from my array when triplets are way too more and how to count all shows triplets ? What is better, have this triplet in function or in the int main (void) ? Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `return` from the function in

```
if(array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == K) {
  printf("Triplet Found : %d, %d, %d\n", array[i], array[j], array[k]);
  return 1;
}
```

You can do instead something like this:

```
int triplet(int *array, int size, int K) {
  int i, j, k;
  int found = 0; /* triplets whose sum is equal to K */
  for(i = 0; i < size-2; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < size-1; j++) {
      for (k = j+1; k < size; k++) {
        if(array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == K) {
          printf("Triplet Found : %d, %d, %d\n", array[i], array[j], array[k]);
          found++;
        }           
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but now it taking zero to for K=7 it takes 1+6+0 and i want in without using zero because then its like not triplet but doublet :D

Comment: Replace `if(array[i] + array[j] + array[k] == K) {` with `int a = array[i], b = array[j], c = array[k]; if (a && b && c && a + b + c == K) {`.

Comment: its funny but now it only show again only 1 triplet :D but without this its show more triplets but triplet like 1+3+0 = 4 :D

Comment: So that's what your data is like. If you don't have other questions, please mark the answer as correct if it was helpful.